# Error: createContext only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it

Tags: reactjs, next.js14, shadcnui

In Next.js 14 I have a page in app directory where i wantend to create Link with button styles so i imported cva buttonVariants and use it, but it is giving error if i import it from index.ts file

```
// @/app/page.tsx
import { buttonVariants } from '@/components/ui'
import Link from 'next/link'

function TestsPage() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Link
                href={...}
                className={cn(buttonVariants({ variant: 'outline' }))}
            >
                <Plus
                    className='mr-1'
                    size={20}
                />
                Create new test
            </Link>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
// @/components/ui/index.ts
export * from './button'
```

```
// @/components/ui/button.tsx

import { cva, type VariantProps } from 'class-variance-authority'

import { cn } from '@/lib/utils'
import { Loader2 } from 'lucide-react'

const buttonVariants = cva(
    '...',
    {
        variants: {
            variant: {
                // ..some variants
            }
        },
        defaultVariants: {
            variant: 'default',
            size: 'default',
        },
    },
)

export interface ButtonProps
    extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>,
        VariantProps<typeof buttonVariants> {
    asChild?: boolean
    isLoading?: boolean
}

const Button = React.forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, ButtonProps>(
    {
            ...
    },
)
Button.displayName = 'Button'

export { Button, buttonVariants }
```

when i import it directly from button file it works or when i make page client, but i don't like both options

I want to import buttonVariants from index.ts file and use it in page.tsx

Answer (score 1):

Update your `index.ts` file as follows:

```js
// @/components/ui/index.ts
"use client"
export * from './button'
```

Changes:

- Added the `"use client"` at the top of file

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't help. 
I got this error:
Attempted to call buttonVariants() from the server but buttonVariants is on the client. It's not possible to invoke a client function from the server, it can only be rendered as a Component or passed to props of a Client Component.